# Simple node file server with auth

Tags: node.js

I need to host just a simple file sharing site with basic auth and I'm having a problem doing it.  I had chatgpt (sorry) write me the following as I'm not very proficient in node.

```
const express = require('express');
const basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 80;

const username = 'username';
const password = 'password';

const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const user = basicAuth(req);

  if (!user || user.name !== username || user.pass !== password) {
    res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }

  return next();
};

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
app.use('/files', authMiddleware, express.static('public'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I can access the server and the auth seems to work but I'm getting "Cannot GET /files/" after I auth.  I do have a directory named `public` in the same directory as `server.js`.  Also if possible I would like to automatically redirect to /files from / (chatgpt doesn't understand that ask).

Comment: As for redirecting, try `app.get("/", (_, res) => res.redirect("/files"))`

Comment: What is the *actual* HTTP response + statuscode for the URL you're trying to open.

Comment: @Evert I've updated the question